# Interpreting Random Effects for Poisson GLMM

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, poisson-distribution, random-effects-model, glmm

There seem to be a few answers for normally distributed models, but after some searching I could only come across [this page](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel/13586) for Poisson mixed models. I want to be certain I am **interpreting the random effects properly**.

I'll paste my output and provide the reproducible code at the bottom. Let's pretend we are counting species of moths in two different habitat groups on 5 different individual trees.

```
summary(fit)
    # Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
    # (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
    # Family: poisson  ( log )
    # Formula: Count ~ Group + (1 | ID)
    # Data: df
    # 
    # AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    # 132.2    135.2    -63.1    126.2       17 
    # 
    # Scaled residuals: 
    #   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    # -1.8708 -1.0472 -0.2687  0.6795  2.3808 
    # 
    # Random effects:
    #   Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
    # ID     (Intercept) 0.123    0.3507  
    # Number of obs: 20, groups:  ID, 5
    # 
    # Fixed effects:
    #   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
    # (Intercept)   1.0236     0.5339   1.917  0.05520 . 
    # Group         0.9226     0.3502   2.634  0.00843 **
    #   ---
    #   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    # 
    # Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    #   (Intr)
    # Group -0.945
```

Ok. So I think that exp(0.9226) = 2.51 means that in the second group, Counts are up by 2.5 x what they are in the first group. That's fine, it makes sense if we look at the plots I made (in code below).

But what about the random effects?
First, I assume I should exponentiate them as well...?

exp(0.3507) = 1.42
How can I interpret this number? Is it the average standard deviation *within* IDs? As in, within any group, the count differs by a standard deviation of 1.42? This might mean that we would find that most counts within a group would be within exp(1.96*0.3507) = 1.98 above or below the mean for that ID? Or, that in general the spread of count data within one tree would fall within exp(2*1.96*0.357) = 4 species?

Thierry's explanation on the hyperlinked page was that the highest 97th percentile tree would have 4 X the number of species as the lowest, so I wonder if I'm getting this wrong - as in, the actual interpretation would be that over ALL IDs, the counts differ by 4X from the lowest counts to the highest.

**What is the correct interpretation?**

Here the example:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A",
                        "B", "B", "B", "B",
                        "C", "C", "C", "C",
                        "D", "D", "D", "D",
                        "E", "E", "E", "E"),
                 Count = c(1, 4, 5, 9, 
                           2, 3, 4, 10, 
                           8, 12, 21, 14, 
                           15, 17, 12, 23, 
                           17, 27, 12, 19),
                 Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1,  
                           1, 1, 1, 1, 
                           1, 1, 1, 1,  
                           2, 2, 2, 2, 
                           2, 2, 2, 2))

fit <- glmer(Count ~ Group + (1|ID), data = df, family = "poisson")


ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Count, group = Group)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, y = Count)) +
  geom_point()

ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, y = Count)) +
  geom_boxplot()

summary(fit)
```

Comment: The last sentence of the lme4 book might help: "We should also be aware that the random effects are defined on the linear predictor scale and not on the probability scale." http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf